# Entrez (Biopython) esearch and efetch not returning sequence as expected

Tags: python, covid-19, genbank, entrez, virus

I'm trying to use Entrez (through Biopython) to download the sequence of a TMV replicase gene.

I have the following code:

```py
# Lookup ID
search = Entrez.esearch(db='gene', term='Tobacco mosaic virus[Orgn] AND replicase')
read = Entrez.read(search)
idlist = read["IdList"]

# Fetch sequence
search = Entrez.efetch(db='gene', id=idlist[0], retmode='text', rettype='gb')
read = SeqIO.read(search, "genbank")
tmv_replicase = read.seq
```

But when I run it it throws the exception on the `SeqIO.read` line: `ValueError: No records found in handle`.

The IDs provided in idlist are: `['1494081', '1494082']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to fetch from the database `nucleotide` instead of `gene` ?

```
# load modules
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Entrez

# Lookup ID
search = Entrez.esearch(db='nucleotide', term='Tobacco mosaic virus[Orgn] AND replicase')
read = Entrez.read(search)
idlist = read["IdList"]

# Fetch sequence
search = Entrez.efetch(db='nucleotide', id=idlist[0], retmode='text', rettype='gb')
read = SeqIO.read(search, "genbank")
tmv_replicase = read.seq
```

It returns

```
>>> read
SeqRecord(seq=Seq('GTATTTTTACAACAATTACCAACAACAACAAACAACAAACAACATTACAATTAC...GGG'), id='MN912489.1', name='MN912489', description='Tobacco mosaic virus isolate TMV:BR:SC:02:01, complete genome', dbxrefs=[])
>>> tmv_replicase
Seq('GTATTTTTACAACAATTACCAACAACAACAAACAACAAACAACATTACAATTAC...GGG')
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets me what I wanted. Out of interest though, do you know why using the gene database for this wouldn't work? (I'm new to Entrez).

Comment: It is simply 2 differents databases. The ID into `nucleotide` is not the same into `gene`. Thus from the website NCBI it is possible to extract a fasta from a gene query it doesn't seem possible with biopython https://biopython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter_entrez.html

Comment: If you want to filter your queries from the `nucleotide` database in order to get only the specific genes you can check my code as an example: https://gitlab.mbb.univ-montp2.fr/bev/target_genes_from_ncbi/-/blob/master/select_query_gene_sequences_ncbi.py